# Get the average from list of values of foreign key object fields

Tags: django

I am making a movie rating app. Each movie can be rated by users.

```
class MovieRating(models.Model):
    movie = models.OneToOneField(Movie)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserRating')
    average_rating = ???

    or whichever is better

    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        ???

class UserRating(models.Model):
    movie_rating = models.ForeignKey(MovieRating)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(10)
        ]
    )
    review = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('movie', 'user')
```

I want to get the average rating of for that movie. Meaning

`average_rating = (Total rating by user for a MovieRating) / (Total users of MovieRating)`

I can get the total users of a MovieRating by

`movie_rating.users.count()`

But how do I get the rating of every users in Total? Or else what can I do to get the average rating for a movie?

update:

Now I am doing this way, but I don't know whether this is the right way to go:

```
def average_rating(self):
    if self.users.count() == 0:
        return 0.0
    rates = 0
    rating_list = [user_rating.rating for user_rating in self.userrating_set.all()]
    for r in rating_list:
        rates = r + rates
    return rates / self.users.count()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Django supports aggregation queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), including averaging. In your case you can aggregate on the related field through the object's reverse relation to its [intermediary model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany). Since aggregations are performed natively by the database, they are generally recommended over manually calculating their values.

So in your average rating property method

```
from django.db.models import Avg

...

@property
def average_rating(self):
    return self.userrating_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
```

Comment: How can I use round() with this? Since `(1+5+2)/3=8/3=2.6666...67`, I would like to round up to 1 decimal place, such as 2.7. But `round(self.userrating_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg'], 1)` is giving me type error **a float is required**.

Comment: Rounding works when I try it on an aggregated average, does it correctly return the 2.666... you expect? That line alone should work fine, so it may be an issue relating to the surrounding code.

Comment: You can use `quantize()` to achieve rounding to 1 decimal place. Example usage: `self.userrating_set.aggregate(Avg('rating')).get('rating__avg').quantize(Decimal("1.0"))` This would also require `from decimal import Decimal`.

Comment: I know already how to find the Avg() value but how can I define this avg value into another model to be used in an endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sum([rate.rating for rate in movie_rating.userrating_set.all()])
```

Comment: Yes, I was also kind of doing this way. Is it ok to loop even if there are many objects in a list?

Comment: it is either that or you recalculate the rating once a new rating has been added. That means that either you recalculate on save or you create a post save for that.